# Power BI Conditional filtering

Tags: powerbi, filtering, dax

I'm having some issue regarding the filtering in Power BI/DAX. I have an example below. What I'm trying to achieve is to write a measure to filter out the rows where column 1 is "A" and Column 2 is "aa" and then sum the total of the rest of rows.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you update the question with what logic are you using to filter out those columns?

Comment: Thanks, question updated. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CALCULATE like this:

```
Sum of Filtered Values = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('DataTable'[Amount]);
    'DataTable'[Column1] = "A";
    'DataTable'[Column2] = "aa"
)
```

The two rows below SUM() are filter arguments in the CALCULATE function. Each of the arguments removes all other filtering on their respective columns and then CALCULATE generates a table where the two filter arguments are combine with a logic AND, hence CALCULATE will SUM all [Amounts] where [Column1] is "A" and [Column2] = "aa".

This is basic DAX workflow. Read about CALCULATE, understand how the filter functions work (and their inherrent pitfalls), and learn to love it.